How to pass returned value to different component
I'm trying to be able to load a product in a separate child component (which is enabled when a user clicks a product from a product list rendered map on the parent component).
I've set up a function to .filter through the list of products so just the product at the index value (that matches the ID of the product clicked from the product list) and return it in a variable.
In Parent Component
let focussedProduct = "";

const viewProduct = (productID) => {
  focussedProduct = focusProduct.filter((e, index, array)=>{
    return index == productID
  })
  console.log(focussedProduct[0]);
};

<div className='product' key={product.id} onClick={() => viewProduct(product.id)}>

Which console logs this, so it's returning what I need when clicking random items:

However I'm really struggling to pass the returned value/data to the child component to map it and start rendering that product, I thought it would be as easy as passing the variable like this.
Parent component
<Product 
  focussedProduct = {focussedProduct}
/>

Child component
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Product = (props) => {  
    console.log(props.focussedProduct)  
}

export default Product;    

But it's not returning anything in the console to use/map. So I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong and I'm sure it's simple but I'm not getting there even after doing a bit of googling. Help is much appreciated.

check what is the output of viewProduct. you are console logging inside, but it doesn't look like you are returning anything after that.

It seems your problem is that when you call viewProduct you update focussedProduct but it is not a state variable and no re-render happens.
Actually you have access to the product during click so you could just directly store that in state without performing the filter.
Or you could do as you have just additionally store the result (focussedProduct) in state, or you can just store id of the clicked item in state and perform filter during render as here:
export default function Form() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id: 'item1', label: 'label1' },
    { id: 'item2', label: 'label2' },
  ]);

  let focusedProduct = items.filter((x) => x.id === id)?.[0];

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        {items?.map((y) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setId(y.id);
            }}
          >
            {y.label}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {focusedProduct && <div>Clicked: {focusedProduct.label} </div>}
    </form>
  );
}
 


Thanks I would like to know more about the storing the clicked product in the state. I thought I needed to filter the useState of products to not mutate it, to then allow for changing it to different products that are clicked? or have I got that wrong?

@Chobbit Sorry I did not understand the question.

No worries @Giorgi, Using what you have put above I have managed to figure out what I needed. Storing the product Id as a useState on click was the key and then using your: let focussedProduct = focusProduct.filter((x) => x.id === id)?.[0]; code to check against it. This all meant I could pass it to the new component as I did before with: <Product focussedProduct = {focussedProduct} /> and call it in the child component with: {props.focussedProduct?.title} and it works. I'll mark yours as the answer, thanks :)
